# not able to convert string to float in python and how to train the model with this dataset

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with columns: age (float type), gender (str type), regions (str type) and charges(float type).

I want to predict charges using age gender and region as features, how can I do that in scikit learn?

I have tried something but it shows `"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'northwest' "`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/insurance.csv')
X = df.loc[:,['age','sex','region']].values
y = df.loc[:,['charges']].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200,decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: `region` is a categorical variable. To use it in prediction, you might have to transform it, say using one-hot encoding, etc. Read more here : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/

Comment: ok and what about gender...?? if I encode region northeast,northwest,southeast,southwest as 0,1,2,3 respectively....then if I encode gender; male, female as 0,1 then there will be same value...will it affect the process??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `region` contains strings, which can't be used as such in the SVM classifier as it is not a vector.

Threfore you have to turn this column into something that is usable by the SVM. Here is an example by changing `region` into a categorical series:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[20,30,40,50],
              'sex':['male','female','female','male'],
              'region':['northwest','southwest','northeast','southeast'],
              'charges':[1000,1000,2000,2000]})
df.sex = (df.sex == 'female')
df.region = pd.Categorical(df.region)
df.region = df.region.cat.codes
X = df.loc[:,['age','sex','region']]
y = df.loc[:,['charges']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = svm.SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200,decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Another way to approach this problem is to use one-hot vector encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[20,30,40,50],
              'sex':['male','female','female','male'],
              'region':['northwest','southwest','northeast','southeast'],
              'charges':[1000,1000,2000,2000]})
df.sex = (df.sex == 'female')
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.region)],axis = 1).drop('region',1)
X = df.drop('charges',1)
y = df.charges
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = svm.SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200,decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Yet another approach is to perform label encoding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df.region = le.fit_transform(df.region)
```

This list of methods is of course non-exhaustive, and they perform differently according to your problem.

The use of non-numeric data is a non-trivial one, and requires a bit of knowledge on the existing techniques (I encourage you to go and search in kaggle's forums where you can find valuable informations).

Comment: I have used `LabelEncoder()` and my problem is resolved..is it the correct way to tackle this problem??

Comment: It's one way among others. `pd.Categorical` makes no assumption on the target and just split the different values and hash them as integers, `Labelencoder` uses knowledge of the target, which makes a more accurate mapping provided that your training data is efficiently distributed. One hot encoding creates binary dimensions which are more or less well used by classifiers. This is off course not a comprehensive list, plz take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139129/how-to-recode-categorical-variable-into-numerical-variable-when-using-svm-or-neu for more information.